# Is this a security vulerability, XSS or CSRF?

Tags: ajax, security, web-applications, xss, csrf

Lets say my javascript makes an ajax-request and in the callback-function it does eval(response_text) without checking the response_text for anything.

Something tells me this is not good, but why and how could it be epxloited? Wont it be always my server which will send it good data?

Comment: You shouldnt follow this practice... send back something which helps you decide what code to run on the client side, not the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

That would be vulnerable to an XSS if it comes from an untrusted source. The attacker can call a function on your site.

Think of a situation where the attacker appends a script tag to the document that loads a script from his site.

Comment: What if the eval(response_txt+"(const_argu)") the rsponse_text is cat'ed with a constant string as the argument to eval?

Comment: That could still be exploited given that response_txt is arbitrary text. If you fully trust the source of response_txt then you probably can live with the risk.
e.g. if response_txt = "something_malicious();what_you_want" what you end up with is eval("something_malicious();what_you_want(const_argu)").
but you can easily validate response text if it should be strictly an alphanumeric string with maybe an underscore.